# onSubmit button not redirecting to Profile component page

Tags: reactjs, react-router, onsubmit

So I want my submit button from Signup to direct me to my Profile page in my react app. But I cannot get it to work with the suggestions given online. I would like to know what my errors are in my code.
I want to be able to click the Sign Up button and be able to get to the /profile route of my application. I am not sure why it doesn't work and it doesnt show any errors anywhere, it just goes to my Express POST route at the moment.
sign-up.component.js

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Redirect } from 'react-router';
import { withRouter } from 'react-router';

export default class SignUp extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            firstName: '',
            lastName: '',
            email: '',
        }
    }
    onChange = (e) => {
        this.setState({ [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
      }

  onSubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        const {firstName, lastName, email} = this.state;

        fetch('http://localhost:9000/users/new', {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
            'Content-Type' : 'application/json'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(this.state)
    })
    .then((result) => result.json())
    .then((info) => {console.log(info)})
    this.props.history.push('/profile');    }

render() {
        return (
            <form method='POST' action='http://localhost:9000/users/new'>
                <h3>Sign Up</h3>

                <div className="form-group">
                    <label>First name</label>
                    <input type="text" className="form-control" placeholder="First name" name ="firstName"/>
                </div>

                <div className="form-group">
                    <label>Last name</label>
                    <input type="text" className="form-control" placeholder="Last name" name="lastName" />
                </div>

                <div className="form-group">
                    <label>Email address</label>
                    <input type="email" className="form-control" placeholder="Enter email" name="email" />
                </div>

                <div className="form-group">
                    <label>Password</label>
                    <input type="password" className="form-control" placeholder="Enter password" />
                </div>

                <button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary btn-block" onClick={this.onSubmit}>Sign Up</button>
                
                <p className="forgot-password text-right">
                    Already registered <a href="#">sign in?</a>
                </p>
            </form>
        );
    }
```

App.js

```
import React from 'react';
import '../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import './App.css';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route, Link } from "react-router-dom";

import Login from "./components/login.component";
import SignUp from "./components/sign-up.component";
import Profile from "./components/profile";

function App() {
  return (<Router>
    <div className="App">
      <nav className="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark fixed-top">
        <div className="container">
          <Link className="navbar-brand" to={"/sign-in"}>Code Process Reviews</Link>
          <div className="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarTogglerDemo02">
            <ul className="navbar-nav ml-auto">
              <li className="nav-item">
                <Link className="nav-link" to={"/sign-in"}>Login</Link>
              </li>
              <li className="nav-item">
                <Link className="nav-link" to={"/sign-up"}>Sign up</Link>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </nav>

      <div className="auth-wrapper">
        <div className="auth-inner">
          <Switch>
            <Route exact path='/' component={Login} />
            <Route path="/sign-in" component={Login} />
            <Route path="/sign-up" component={SignUp} />
            <Route path="/profile" component={Profile} />
          </Switch>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div></Router>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

you cannot use `this` in arrow functions change the arrow syntax to normal
from `onSubmit(e)=>{}` to `function onSubmit(e){}`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using history.push set state flag for redirection

e.g

```
    this.state = {
       ...
       url: '',
    }
    
    ....
    
    // After network response 
    this.setState({url: '/profile'});
    
    
    // And in Component
    { this.state.url ? <Redirect to={this.state.url} /> : null }
```